# Bluetooth latency too high

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, blueman

Bluetooth latency too is high.

I have 3 bluetooth devices connected.
When 2 is connected, its working fine but not with 3 devices.

**Laptop**: Asus ROG

**Devices**: MX Master 3, MX Keys & JBL Home Theater.

**OS**: Ubuntu 22.04

**Issues**:
When 3 devices are connected mouse pointer is lagging. Key press delay & Home Theater sound quality got down highly.

**hciconfig -a**

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: A4:34:D9:A5:B8:87  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:370263 acl:17768 sco:0 events:7022 errors:0
    TX bytes:4509150 acl:6888 sco:0 commands:110 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
    Name: 'torque'
    Class: 0x7c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Thanks

Comment: What devices? How do you tell that latency is high? [Edit] your question to add this.

Comment: @vidarlo Thanks. I updated